# I tried to press Ctrl+T using Selenium (Java) in the Chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, action

I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> using Selenium (Java) in the Chrome browser. There is no error in the console, but the browser does not open a new tab. I want to know why this happens. I tried to find on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find any accurate answer.

This is my code:

```
package automation1;

import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Action {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\asus\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Jar\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver chromedriver = new ChromeDriver();
        chromedriver.get("https://xenodochial-meninsky-118d47.netlify.app/");
        chromedriver.manage().window().fullscreen();
        
        Actions a = new Actions(chromedriver) ;
          Thread.sleep(3000) ;
        a.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t").build().perform() ;
        
    }

}
```

Why doesn't this not open a new tab in the Chrome browser?

Comment: According to [Working with windows and tabs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/), you should use `driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);` to create a new tab. Are you just looking to create a new tab, or do you insist on using Ctrl+T?

Comment: It shows error exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method newWindow(SafariDriver.WindowType) is undefined for the type WebDriver.TargetLocator

Comment: It seems you have imported the wrong WindowType as the error mentions `SafariDriver.WindowType`. You should use `org.openqa.selenium.WindowType`

Comment: Now this error comes Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 WindowType cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: It should exist, see https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WindowType.html

Comment: It should exit, but I don't know by this is not imported into my system. Anything I can do to make I happen?

Comment: @Tejveernaruka driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB); will work with latest ver of selenium ie. selenium 4, i hope u are using the same.

Comment: yes, I am using the latest version of selenium but when I want to import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType package then eclipsed shows the error .@AbhishekDhoundiyal. Can Anything I do to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution **without** using `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions`.

For selenium 3.141.59:

**pom.xml dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code:**

```
package tests;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TejveerNaruka {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String chromedriverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        
        // open new tab using javascript
        jsExecutor.executeScript("window.open()");
        
        // get Window handles, identifications of all browser tabs and windows
        List<String> windowHandles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        
        // switch to second tab
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(1));
        
        // prints title of the second tab (empty line)
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        // navigate driver in the second tab
        driver.get("https://www.zemancountdown.cz/");

        // prints title of the second tab           
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        
        // close second tab
        jsExecutor.executeScript("window.close()");
        
        // switch to the first tab
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(0));
        
        //prints title of the first tab 
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016}) on port 18498
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Pro 12, 2022 12:50:43 ODP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers

Miloš Zeman Countdown
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
```

Another example now with selenium 4:

**pom.xml dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Code:**

```
package tests;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class TejveerNaruka {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String chromedriverPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        // navigate driver and print title
        driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        
        // create second driver in new tab
        WebDriver driver2 = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
        
        // prints empty line
        System.out.println(driver2.getTitle());
        
        // navigate driver2 and print title
        driver2.get("https://www.zemancountdown.cz/");
        System.out.println(driver2.getTitle());
        
        driver2.quit();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016}) on port 24322
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers

Miloš Zeman Countdown
```

Comment: This is working. But  why I can't import the package  org.openqa.selenium.WindowType  ?

Comment: Bcs of selenium version. `org.openqa.selenium.WindowType` requires version 4. I've updated my answer with another example.

Comment: And why the control + t is not working to open a new tab? This is also because of the selenium version?

Comment: No there will be another cause. Avoid using `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` except moving to element. If you get unpredictably a different window, the key press/release event is fired in wrong window.

Comment: Can you elaborate I didn't get your point Please?

Comment: For example if browser is updated to new version usualy a new tab with release info is opened at the start -> unpredictably different tab.